# Understanding login state

Tags: authentication, cypress

I want to use Cypress to implement automation.

Our systems require a user to be logged in and perform certain actions. The issue I have is when I create different test cases the user gets logged out and I have to re use certain code which I don't want to because it's bad practice.

How can I use the same state so that user is logged in for the entire session and the test cases will flow without having to login for each one.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be how is the login feature implemeted? You don't mention that, but it's key to suggesting any course of action here.

Therefore, I can only guess. I'll share one example, you can try to tweak it to your situation and see if it works.

In an application I test, I can login via an API, that is calling a POST `/users/login` endpoint with credentials in the body. Apart from that I also have to provide API key in Authorization header. I can prepare a Cypress custom command that does this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('apiLogin', ({ email, password }) => {
  cy
    .request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${Cypress.env('apiBaseUrl')}/users/login`,
      body: {
          email: email,
          password: password
      },
      headers: {
          Authorization: `ApiKey ${Cypress.env('apiKey')}`
      }
    });
});
```

Then anywhere in my tests, I can use it to log in:

```js
cy
  .fixture('credentials')
  .then(user => {
    cy
      .apiLogin(user);
  });
```

Ok, but what does the request return?

In my case, the request returns a refresh token and access token. If I set them in cookies, I'm logged in:

```js
cy
  .fixture('credentials')
  .then(users => {
    cy
      .apiLogin(users.confirmed)
      .then(res => {
        cy
          .setCookie('AUTH_TOKEN', res.body.accessToken)
          .setCookie('REF_TOKEN', res.body.refreshToken);
      });
  });
```

A good place to put this is in before hook:

```js
before(() => {
  cy
    .fixture('credentials')
    .then(user => {
      cy
        .apiLogin(user)
        .then(res => {
          cy
            .setCookie('AUTH_TOKEN', res.body.accessToken)
            .setCookie('REF_TOKEN', res.body.refreshToken);
        });
  });
});
```

and to use the same tokens across multiple tests in the same describe block, I need to tell Cypress to preserve the cookies:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('AUTH_TOKEN', 'REF_TOKEN');
});
```

I don't know if something like this might work with your system. But it can serve as a general idea on how to log in in tests, namely:

- it's a good idea to use an API, it's faster than using a UI
- whether a user is logged in or not could be controlled by a cookie or cookies
- Cypress can preserve cookies

Some links for further study:

- [Cypress.Cookies](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies)
- [Cypress request command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request)
- [other authentication schemes such as Auth0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication)
- Cypress examples in their [repo](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples), examples directories for login start with `logging-in*`

In general, it's worth understanding how your system works before diving into writing some automation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thourough repsonse...our login is simple just to provide a username and password and I think the login session is saved in the cookie.

Comment: @ChristianGeorgeson: then you should be able to achieve something similar to what I showed in my answer.